# how to get route directions in GMSmaps

Tags: ios, google-maps, directions

what i have done is:

i put camera on some latitude and longitude
and marker onthe same  position

i have two questions
1)how to place them in current position 
2)how to get the routes between two points

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // maps


    GMSCameraPosition *camera=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.714353 longitude:-74.005973 zoom:16];
    mapview=[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 140.0, 210.0) camera:camera];
    mapview.myLocationEnabled=NO;
    self.view=mapview;
    GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.714353, -74.005973);
    marker.title=@"chennai";
    marker.map=mapview;
    self.view=mapview;




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get the current location by using **myLocation** property of google map view.
   First enable your **myLocation**.

   ```
   mapview.myLocationEnabled=YES;
   ```

   Then set the position as

   ```
   NSLog(@"%f %f",myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   ```
2. If you want to get direction between two points then request as

   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters

Parameters are **origin**, **destination**, **sensor**.
Refere documents [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests)

```
-(IBAction)getDirection   {
    NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"URL_STRING"]; 
    NSURLRequest *req = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval:30.0 ];
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *res;
    NSData *d = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                   returningResponse:&res
                                               error:&err ];
}
```

Comment: can we directly use the api on button press

Comment: you can make this request on a button action handler

Comment: can you give me a sample code for uibutton click so that the url is called

Comment: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit"

Comment: origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit